# Recommended Dart project layout for public, private, app, server and/or test files?

Tags: dart

What is the recommended **Dart project layout** if I have both app (client) and server code as well as private lib resources and test files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The project layout shared by Dan Rubel and Eric Clayberg (in a presentation at the [2013-12-18 Googleplex Eclipse Day](https://www.dartlang.org/slides/2013/12/developing-dart-editor.pdf)) is something like this:

```
my_app/
  pubspec.yaml
  README.md
  bin/
    start_my_app             <-- server-side code
  lib/
    public_code.dart         <-- shared public code
    src/
      internal_code.dart     <-- private code
  test/
    my_app_test.dart
  web/                       <-- client-side code
    index.html
    main.dart
    main.css
```

Comment: Also see the related Pub Package Layout Conventions which details more about the directory hierarchy: https://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html