# Dart project configuration for both server and client programming?

Tags: dart

I want to develop a Dart project for both server and client programming;
obviously, I need to share code between the two.

I got [dart package layout](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout) basics.
My question: is there one advised configuration? Do I have more than one option?
Like one project with both client server parts in it. 
Or, more than one project with the various parts split between them...

I found other questions on SO, but:

- they are 'work in progress' and really old
- contains outdated links

The most interesting questions are:

- [recommended-dart-project-layout-for-public-private-app-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380293/recommended-dart-project-layout-for-public-private-app-server-and-or-test-fil)
- [how-to-organize-mixed-http-server-web-client-dart-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884103/how-to-organize-mixed-http-server-web-client-dart-project-files)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest to split it into three packages.

- client
- server
- shared

The main advantage is, that packages used in client or server don't need to be compatible with each other, only within client+shared or within server+shared they need to be compatible, but that's usually a notable smaller set. 
Less dependencies means less opportunity of having conflicting dependency constraints.

A disadvantage might come up when your IDE doesn't make it easy to work with projects that's spread over several packages. IntelliJ does this well. I don't know about others.